# Getting notification when an answer is updated

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications

Is it normal that I don't get a notification in my inbox when someone updated his/her answer (that means an edit has been made) on one of my questions? If yes, wouldn't this be a nice feature? I'd love to know when new information is available, without having to visit every question again.

Comment: I'm afraid it's normal. That's why I comment `@OP` when I think he might be interested with my changes. At least he'll see my comment.

Comment: If questions are marked as favorite you can see the updated questions highlighted in your favs tab from user profile page.